# How to deploy restful web APIs in Mulesoft

Tags: rest, deployment, mule

We are using Visual studio for API development. Our client want us to use Mule soft for API management. 
Can anyone provide the steps or related article about how to deploy and manage existing restful Web APIs in Mulesoft.

Answer (score 1):

You'll only be able to deploy and manage Mule apps on CloudHub or an on-prem mule server, however, you can manage the API of another application by creating an API in API Manager and deploying a proxy. You can find more information about this [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/proxy-latest-concept) and [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/proxy-deploy-cloudhub-latest-task):